# Java Format Lines So Columns Line Up

Tags: java, string, format

I am trying to format a line of data in Java so each column lines up. I am using tabs currently, but it does not seem to be working.

This is what I am trying :

```
System.out.printf("Town\tDate\tWind Speed\tDirection\tTemp(F)\tTemp(C)\tWind Chill(C)\tReporter\n");

System.out.printf(town + "\t" + date + "\t" + windSpeed + "\t" + direction + "\t" + 
                            getFahrenheit(tempC) + "\t" + tempC + "\t" + getWindChillFactor(windSpeed, tempC) + "\t" +
                            reporterCode + "\n");
```

**Update:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` method you are using accepts a format string as the first parameter and the arguments interpreted according to the format. In your case you want a minimum number of spaces for a string. This can be achieved with the correct format string such as:

```
System.out.println("%20s", town);
```

This will print town as a string with a minimum width of 20 characters. There are rules for right aligning, rounding floating points etc. See [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for details.

Comment: It's better but it still doesn't look like the picture below.

Comment: System.out.printf("Town%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s", "Date", "Wind Speed", "Direction", "Temp(F)", "Temp(C)", "Wind Chill(C)", "Reporter"); System.out.printf(town + "%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s", date, windSpeed, direction, getFahrenheit(tempC), tempC, 
     getWindChillFactor(windSpeed, tempC), reporterCode + "\n");

Comment: @bob yes I wasn't planning on providing the answer just give you an idea of how to solve the problem. I would think your dates, windSpeed etc would be numbers rather than strings? Also suggest the newline is in the format rather than one of the argument values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in Java 8 it should work:

```
public class test  {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Town","Date","Wind Speed","Direction","Temp(F)","Temp(C)","Wind Chill","Reporter");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Portland","12/10/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","orango","12/10/15","2.50","NW","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","calais","12/10/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","calais","12/10/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Portland","12/10/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Portland","12/10/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","bangor","12/15/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","orango","12/19/15","2.50","NW","36.50","2.50","1.56","PS");

    }
}
```

To fix your update image :

```
 System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Orono","12/15/15","2.50","W","36.50","2.50","1.56","OT");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%s\n","Orono","12/19/15","3.10","NW","36.72","2.90","0.42","SS");
```

Try the above code:

Comment: I have updated my post with the output! It almost works perfectly!

Comment: For some reason the "Orono" ones are still off slightly.

Comment: @bob if you can't fix share it

Comment: In your code put "Orono" instead of "orango". Let me know if it's off for you.

Comment: @bob yes. it is my code only to fix your line  `Orono` i ll update my answer seperately